# stringWithFormat or stringFromDate

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

*Simple / basic question:*

If I do **not** care to format the date being obtained, what are the performance differences between the two?

```
 NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
 NSSting *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:"%@", date];
```

&&

```
 NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
```

Sorry for such a simple question, I just am not finding what I am looking for searching google and can't find a question on here that addresses it.

The three objects below seem very expensive when working with a large list of CFDateRefs and I am attempting to create a work around.

Any advice on that would be awesome too, but I am more focused on the question at hand.

- NSDateComponenets
- NSCalendar
- NSDateFormatter

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those will likely have similar performance (the -description method that stringWithFormat calls will use a date formatter internally).

If you create the date formatter once, then use it for many dates, you'll get much much better performance.

Comment: thanks for your response. I was hoping for a little bit more clarity and am going to wait a few days and if nothing, I will accept your answer.

Comment: I do agree with the declaration call, but I am accessing dates and comparing  non-stop in the project I am working on. Really hoping to cut back on the bottlenecks.

Comment: @ChrisHaze, Catfish_Man gave you a great "good practice" advice.
I'd also would like to suggest that you should not only init the NSDateFormatter once, but you should also set in the same place *setDateStyle* if you have any - small performance improvement